# Telegram Bot: Game Did not start

Tags: javascript, telegram-bot, telegraf

I am trying to run my game inside telegram in-app browser.

Below are my code so far

```
bot.action('wheeloffortune', ctx => {
    bot.telegram.sendGame(ctx.chat.id, 'wheeloffortune');
})


bot.on("callback_query", function (query) {
    let gameurl = "https://dazzling-ritchie-f3ad20.netlify.app/?id="+query.id;
    bot.answerCallbackQuery({
        callback_query_id: query.id,
        url: gameurl
    });
});

bot.on("inline_query", function(iq) {
    bot.answerInlineQuery(iq.id, [ { type: "game", id: "0", game_short_name: 'wheeloffortune' } ] ); 
});
```

**What I expect**: after clicking the button 'Play wheeloffortune', the game should open in webview.

**What is actually happening**:

this image keep rendering

[image]

any advice is appreciated

Comment: Have you setup your game through @botfather? You should send /newgame to botfather for the setup

Comment: yes, I did setup my game through botfather, that is why I have this link: http://t.me/ScreenForYoutubeLinkBot?game=wheeloffortune

Comment: you can open the link inside ur telegram, the behavior is as I describe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the game [example](https://github.com/telegraf/telegraf/blob/302a46d144993be7a95c5864c87a8d7b79230d1e/docs/examples/game-bot.js) of telegraf:

You can simply use:

```js
bot.gameQuery((ctx) => {
    let queryId = ctx.callbackQuery.id
    let gameurl = "https://dazzling-ritchie-f3ad20.netlify.app/?id="+queryId;
    ctx.answerGameQuery(gameUrl)
})
```

Comment: I have to comment out all my old code and copy and paste the one form the example for it to work :( but thank you fro giving me the example

Comment: I will do more debugging tmr to find out the real reason

Comment: @yongchang The reason I think is that `answerCallbackQuery` is not a method on telegraf. I saw something called `answerCbQuery` instead. You might want to try that